# Configuring WHMCS 500 Server Error In Client Area

Tags: apache, ssl, cpanel, whm, whmcs

I am configuring WHMCS on my dedicated server.

I use cPanel as well.

This is my first time installing WHMCS.

I can access and use the admin panel of WHMCS, but when trying to access the client area I simply get a 500 error.

I have no clue how to even approach this problem.

I have googled quite a bit regarding this error and there is no content.

I assume it's probably something like a check box I forgot to check, but being a first time user I likely missed it.

What steps should I take to resolve this problem?

Note: When trying to access client area on SSL it redirects to non ssl before showing 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the server 500 error: lack of memory in PHP.

Solution: Increased limit for a single script to 128M and issue resolved.

It's unfortunate that a simple "lack of memory" couldn't have been displayed..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an permission OR .htaccess code issues. Please check your Apache server error logs so that you will get exact root cause of this  500 error.

Comment: That was not the appropriate resolution method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to troubleshoot this further. First login to your server via SSH (root user or sudo user - depending on your server configuration( and run following command:

tail -f /usr/local/apache/log/error_log

Now access your client area and see if it generates any error in error log.

Root cause of 500 error can be server's configurations or permissions issue.